# Tkinter: properly pass the instance for unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, tkinter

I am trying to bring the Tkinter script to the testing. The application would be tested without opening the window, just simulate the button click. What I've done seems to be inappropriate, so how could I pass the instance properly? Thanks.

Here is the prototype of my code:

```
# importing Tkinter and math
from tkinter import *
import math

class calc:

  def __init__(self,master):
      """Constructor method"""
      master.title('Calculator')
      master.geometry()
      self.master = master
      self.btn_equal = Button(self.master,text="=",width=11,height=3, fg="red", bg="light green",command=lambda:self.equals()).grid(row=4, column=4,columnspan=2)
      self.e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6,pady=3)

def start_application():
  root = Tk()
  app = calc(root)
  # print(app)
  root.bind_class("Button", "<Button-1>", app.callback)
  return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
  start_application().mainloop()
```

Here is the testing code:

```
import unittest
from tkinter import *
from calculator2 import start_application

class TestCalculator2(unittest.TestCase):

  # start the application, test, and destroy at the end of the test
  async def _start_app(self):
    self.app.mainloop() 

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = start_application()
    self._start_app()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.app.destroy()
    
class TestCalculation(TestCalculator2):

  def test_startup(self):
    title = self.app.winfo_toplevel().title()
    expected = "Calculator"
    self.assertEqual(title, expected)

  def test_addition(self):
    self.btn_equal.invoke() # _Tkinter.tkapp has no attribute, since root is not calc object
```

Comment: I've figured it out that the `self.btn_equal` with `.grid` will always return `None`, so I'll delete the post later if no one posts an answer. Thank you for all your time and attention.

Comment: not necessarily, you can yourself write an answer, and it shouldn't hurt you if you leave the question, should it? on the other hand this kind of question with layout managers returning None has been already answered several times here (and still it gets asked here like every day)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the `Button` widget calls the `grid`, leading to the `NoneType`. The correct way of instantiating a button inside a class with position should be:

```
self.btn_equal = Button(self.master,text="=",width=11,height=3, fg="red", bg="light green",command=lambda:self.equals())
self.btn_equal.grid(row=4, column=4,columnspan=2)
```

On the other hand, the correct way to instantiate the `calc` class **mentioned above** and write a successful unit test with `invoke()`, which clicks the button. The code won't open the GUI, and the testing script works (with warning):

```
class TestCalculator2(unittest.TestCase):

  # start the application, test, and destroy at the end of the test
  async def _start_app(self):
    self.app.mainloop() # the root in Tkinter activates the mainloop()

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = start_application() # activate the root
    self.calc = calc(self.app) # instantiate the calculator
    self._start_app()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.app.destroy()

class TestCalculation(TestCalculator2):
  
  def test_startup(self):
    title = self.app.winfo_toplevel().title()
    expected = "Calculator"
    self.assertEqual(title, expected)

  def test_addition(self):
    self.calc.btn_AC.invoke() # click AC to clear the place
    self.calc.btn_7.invoke() # click button 7
    self.calc.btn_plus.invoke() # click button +
    self.calc.btn_5.invoke() # click button 5
    result = self.calc.btn_equal.invoke() # click button equal, get the value
    self.assertEqual(result, 12)
```

Note that the code snippet just gives a brief idea of how unit testing works on Tkinter, the `calc` class provided is incomplete.